# PhpWord Error - Class 'PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings' not found

Tags: php, phpword

I've uploaded my reporte.php and the other files to the server, it works properly on local but now I can't make it work on the server, the routing is right as I've tried exit(); on phpWord.php so it makes no sense to me that it doesn't finds Settings.php as it is exactly in the same directory, here are my files:

- autoload.php:
  I know $path.$class.('.php') is the standard in loadLibraries, but it works like this for now

```
function loadLibraries($class){

        require_once "/var/www/firescon/public/librerias/PhpOffice/PhpWord/PhpWord.php";
    }

    spl_autoload_register("loadLibraries");


?>
```

The rest of the document is the report, it is 2000 lines long and Im pretty sure it is not the problem, but if you want to see something specific just tell me to, thanks a lot :)

- reporte.php:

```
<?php

require "/var/www/firescon/public/librerias/autoload.php";

use \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord;

$phpWord = new PhpWord();
```

The error happens in the line where $phpWord is declared

Comment: In the loadLibraries function, try to add also "require_once "/var/www/firescon/public/librerias/PhpOffice/PhpWord/Settings.php";" 

Does it work?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be installed using composer, which is the [officially recommended way](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord#installation). Can you just install it that way and use the composer-native autoload?

Comment: it goes on and on with every class inside PhpOffice/PhpWord, but suddenly it stopped getting them when I did 20 or some more requires, dunno

Comment: I will try, give me some minutes

Comment: I cant find a solution, and if I install it via composer the app fails as it changes de composer.json

Answer (score 0):

Obviously as I later on figured out, $class is mandatory, as it is what gets every \PhpOffice\PhpWord class, the thing is that in server the slashes must be / for me, not \ and $class was getting them like this: , so by doing a str_replace("\","/", $class) and sending that instead of $class you get it right.